# How to Callback from dialog class to Fragment

Tags: java, android, datepicker, dialog

I'm trying to update the text on a button after a dialog with a datepicker is closed.
The dialog is instantiated inside of a fragment class and the button risides within that
same class. Here's some code:

Fragment class:

```
select_dob_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_dob_button);
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog();
    datePickerDialog.setButtonText("Select Date Of Birth");
    select_dob_btn.setText(datePickerDialog.getButtonText());
```

The entire dialog class:

```
public class DatePickerDialog extends DialogFragment {

public long dateResult = 0;
String buttonText = "";

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //int listingID = getArguments().getInt("listingID");


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity());

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

    View custom_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_date_picker,null);

    DatePicker datePicker = custom_layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_picker);
    if(dateResult != 0){
        datePicker.init(Globals.getDateYearFromTimeStamp(dateResult), Globals.getDateMonthFromTimeStamp(dateResult),Globals.getDateDayFromTimeStamp(dateResult), null);

    }




    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(custom_layout)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.submit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dateResult = Globals.getTimeStampFromDateDDMMYYYY(datePicker.getDayOfMonth()+"-"+(datePicker.getMonth()+1)+"-"+datePicker.getYear());
                    setButtonText(String.valueOf(Globals.getDateFromTimeStamp(dateResult)));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dateResult = 0;
                    setButtonText(String.valueOf(R.string.register_select_dob));
                    dialogInterface.cancel();

                }
            });


    return builder.create();
}
public DatePickerDialog newInstance() {
    DatePickerDialog f = this;

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
   // args.putInt("listingID", 0);

    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
public void ShowDialog(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = newInstance();

    newFragment.show(fragmentManager, String.valueOf(0));
}

public void setButtonText(String text){
    buttonText = text;
}
public String getButtonText(){
    return buttonText;
}
```

}

Now back on the Fragment class I want to fire this method to update the Select date of birth button:

```
    void RefreshSetBirthdayButton(){

    if(datePickerDialog.dateResult == 0){
        select_dob_btn.setText(R.string.register_select_dob);
    }else{
        datePickerDialog.setButtonText(String.valueOf(Globals.getDateFromTimeStamp(datePickerDialog.dateResult)));
        select_dob_btn.setText(datePickerDialog.getButtonText());
    }

}
```

I've tried to add the onDateChangeLIstener after I init the dialog class but,
I get a NullpointerException.

Any ideas would be helpful Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow `MVC` or `MVVM` pattern which are behind Android architecture. In this case all changes on UI are based on changes in model. So I have to update a model state and UI should be notified on changes in the model.

The right way to do this is to use `ViewModel` class which single instance is shared between your host fragment and dialog fragment. You can use [Sunflower android app](https://github.com/android/sunflower) for reference, it is a bit outdated (e.g. it uses `LiveData` instead of `Kotlin Flows`), but still shows some good architecture decisions.

Another way is to implement interface with callbacks:

```
interface IDialogCallbacks {
  fun onClose()
}
```

Make a host fragment to implement this interface:

```
class MainFragment: Fragment, IDialogCallbacks { /* the rest of code */}
```

In the dialog fragment (or any other child fragment) call parent fragment, check if it implements this interface and if it is then invoke it:

```
    if(getParentFragment() is IDialogCallbacks) {
        (getParentFragment() as IDialogCallbacks).onClose()
    }
```